# C# Entity Framework Delete Cascade Database-First

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, sql-delete, cascade

I have the connection from C# to DB using database-first entity framework that has couple parent tables. For simplicity lets call it TABLE A (which is one of the parents). This table connects to 25 different other tables with foreign key that originate to TABLE A. However, these child tables might have child of their own.

For example:

```
A -> B
A -> C -> D
A -> E
```

The connection between PARENT to CHILD or CHILD to their SUBCHILD is usually 0,1 to MANY. I have set all of the End1 OnDelete to Cascade from None for all the connection strings. I have also set the CHILD to their SUBCHILD to Cascade for End1 OnDelete. So both A -> C and C -> D End1 OnDelete is set to Cascade. However, when I perform a delete from A with id = 5 it keeps failing stating foreign key constraint. But if I modify the table to only have only CHILDs with no CHILD of their own, ie:

```
F -> G
F -> H
F -> I
```

This will work if I delete from table F with id = 2 with no issue, and their CHILD will also get deleted too.

I know that for code-first entity framework we can do something like

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOptional(a => a.UserDetail)
            .WithOptionalDependent()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

But I am stuck using database-first. Also, I really do not want to loop through each of the tables and delete the youngest child first then loop out - I'm pretty sure there is a better way than both.

I believe the issue is if the PARENT has GRANDCHILD then this becomes an issue for cascade DELETE for database first approach.

Comment: Have you tried to delete a row in PARENT using SQL management studio? Does it work? This makes sure that you either configured cascade delete correctly or not

Comment: @DanNguyen No i have not did cascade delete on SQL level. I assumed having done End1 OnDelete = Cascade would be sufficient enough. That seems to work now that i have done it on the SQL management studio. Now what is the point of End1 OnDelete? because even if that is turned to None it still works =/ also i have not done it for any of the tables but it works for direct CHILD but not for grandChilds - any reasons as to why? Nevertheless thanks a lot Dan!!